# Is there js function that replace xml Special Character with their escape sequence?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, escaping, special-characters

I search the web alot and didn't find js function that replace xml Special Character with their escape sequence?
Is there something like this?

I know about the following:

```
Special Character   Escape Sequence Purpose  
&                   &amp;           Ampersand sign 
'                   &apos;          Single quote 
"                   &quot;          Double quote
>                   &gt;            Greater than 
<                   &lt;            Less than
```

is there more? what about writing hexadecimal value like 0×00,
Is this also a problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to escape xml entities in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918868/how-to-escape-xml-entities-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an interesting JS library here: [Client side HTML encoding and decoding](http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode)

Comment: Are you familiar with similar function to C++?

Comment: @DorCohen - no unfortunately not.

Answer (score 14):

I have used this:

```
function htmlSpecialChars(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
    .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
    .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
    .replace(/'/g, "&apos;");
}
```

Comment: and don't forget  .replace(/'/g, "&apos;")

Comment: I would propose `replaceAll('&', '&amp;')` - should be faster than regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You could use PHP's [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) from [the PHPJS project](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars:426).

Comment: I need javascript, it's on client side

Comment: @DorCohen Yes. Check the links in my post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used @Barry Kaye solution because it's works better for me, If I can choose 2 answers I would choose you to but +1

Comment: Are you familiar with similar function to C++?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [Can I escape html special chars in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript/6234804#6234804)

The accepted answer there is this:

```
function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

However, if you're using lodash, then I like cs01's answer from that post:

```
_.escape('fred, barney, & pebbles');
// => 'fred, barney, &amp; pebbles'
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the only characters you need to worry about.

Generally you should be using a DOM interface to build XML documents then you don't need to worry about manually escaping things. That only becomes an issue if you are mashing together strings to build the XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but my favorite way to do it is to let the browser figure it out:

```
function encodeXML(data){
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
    return d.innerHTML;
}

encodeXML('&');
```

Output:

> "&amp;"

You could also use `d.innerText = data;` or `d.textContent = data;`, but `createTextNode()` has the most browser support.