# dojox.grid.DataGrid to XML

Tags: xml, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, xpages-extlib

I need to get the XPages Extension Library DataGrid (`<xe:djxDataGrid>`) content out as XML.

In my client side JavaScipt I'm looping thru all rows, getting values and building my XML using dojox.data.XmlStore.

The problem is that when I try to save the XML, it POSTs as many times as I've added tags and each POST contains `<?xml version="1.0"?>` and one tag.

Here is a simple sample code trying to create a simple XML file:

```
var xml_store = new dojox.data.XmlStore({url: "backend_save_to_file.xsp", rootItem: "tests"});
xml_store.newItem({tagName: "test1"}, "tests");
xml_store.newItem({tagName: "test2"}, "tests");
xml_store.save();
```

Running this JavaScript causes two HTTP POSTs to backend_save_to_file.xsp with these contents:

1. `<?xml version="1.0"?><test1/>`
2. `<?xml version="1.0"?><test2/>`

I would expect one POST containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><tests><test1/><test2/></tests>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I could not get this to work so I'm trying to just build the XML in a string. I'm using `dojox.html.entities.encode` to escape the XML values but looks like this is not the correct way. For example character ä is converted to `&auml;`. IE will not recognize a file containing `&auml;` as XML (I've tried different encodings in xml tag). If I use `&#228;` instead IE will recognize it as XML. How do I escape XML in dojo?

EDIT2: I ended up using this simple encoding:

[how to escape xml entities in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918868/how-to-escape-xml-entities-in-javascript)

But it does not remove the characters that are illegal in XML. Of course there are code snippets that remove them too but I would be surprised if there is no utility in Dojo to do it.

thanks,

- Panu