# Nothing executes after parsing XML string as an XML object

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, web-services, http

I have a form which on click of the submit button runs a function which takes all the form data input, creates a xml string from it and then parses that string as an xml object so it can be sent to an ASP.NET web service.

Here is my function:

```
function postData()
    {
        var cb = document.getElementById('paymentList');
        var selected_cb = cb.options[cb.selectedIndex].text;
        var pguid = getParameterByName('guid');
        var xmlString = '<string>' +
        addField('approver', $('#approver').val()) +
        addField('companyName', $('#companyName').val()) +
        addField('emailAddress', $('#emailaddress').val()) +
        addField('address1', $('#address1').val()) +
        addField('address2', $('#address2').val()) +
        addField('city', $('#city').val()) +
        addField('province', $('#province').val()) +
        addField('country', $('#country').val()) +
        addField('postalCode', $('#postalcode').val()) +
        addField('phoneNumber', $('#phone').val()) +
        addField('paymentMethod', selected_cb);

        xmlString+='<contractData>';
        $('#table tbody tr:has(img[src="images/checkmark.png"])').each(function() {
          xmlString += '<contract>' + addField('vendorPart', $('td:eq(1)', this).text()) +
                addField('description', $('td:eq(2)', this).text()) +
                addField('price', $('td:eq(3)', this).text()) +
                addField('quantity', $('td:eq(4) input', this).val()) + '</contract>';
    });


        xmlString += '</contractData></string>';

        //var vguid = getParameterByName('guid');
        var properid = 'somedata';

        xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xmlString );
        alert("alert");
        $xml = $( xmlDoc );

    $.ajax({

             type: "POST",
             url: "webserviceurl",
             data: {tnWsGuid:properid, xml: $xml},
             dataType: "xml",
             success: function() {
                //window.location.href = 'somePage.html'
                alert("posted");
             },
             error: function ()
             {
                alert("error");
             }
        });

    }
```

On line 33, the alert does not run, anything after the $.parseXML does not execute (placing the alert before the parseXML function does go off). This means it won't post anything to my web service. Any ideas as to why after setting this up as a valid xml object nothing is working afterwards?

Also within the success function you will notice I am changing the page, this does not work in IE, however work's fine in Chrome and FireFox.

** 
Update
**
The error is coming from a input field's data in the XML which has the & symbol inserted with it...any ideas on making it accept that?

```
function addField(name, value) { // Add a single element and value
              return '<' + name + '>' + value + '</' + name + '>';
        }
```

Comment: Press F12 and read the console, most likely the XML isn't valid enough for IE.

Comment: XML5618: Illegal name character. 
, line 1 character 75

Not sure where to go with that...

Comment: Are there any `&`'s in your xml? they need to be escaped. Figure out what character is at character 75 of that xml string.

Comment: I copied and pasted the xml string to the website www.xmlvalidation.com and no errors were found, updating the data in the question above so you can also see it.

Comment: what does `addField` do?

Comment: Don't forget to [search for your error messages](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=XML5618%3A+Illegal+name+character) too!

Comment: I know what the problem is, as I said in one of the fields it has data that uses the ampersand (&), I also updated the above function with the addField function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're forming XML from plain text but not handling the escape syntax for XML. The simplest way is to use an escape function: [how to escape xml entities in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918868/how-to-escape-xml-entities-in-javascript)

Then inside your `addField` function, call this escape function on `value`.

Comment: I don't quite understand...can you provide me an example if possible?

Comment: @Surep: there is an ideal example on the link that Dan has posted. So, instead of `value` in your `addField` function, use `value.replace('&', '&amp;')`. As per the example, you can chain more `replace` methods if you might expect other unencoded entities.