# Get a raw xml from a jQuery/XML object

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm doing a small XML enricher based on JS, which, given a XML file, computes some stuff in the tree, and print on a `<pre></pre>` tag (prettified with highlight.js) the content of my modified file.

Because I use jQuery for computations, I obtain at the end of the process a jQuery object.

For now, my code is only :
`$("#output").append(xmlComputed)`

But obviously, in the browser, I obtain a parsed form of my xml content, without any tags.

So I would like to know what kind of method I can use to obtain the full xml node in string from a jQuery node, like with `.html()` I suppose?

And so, I'll be able to escape then the special characters and print the result.

Thank you in advance!

[Edit] I've ever tried this : [Convert xml to string with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507293/convert-xml-to-string-with-jquery)
But I obtain only the beginning of my xml document, eg `<!--xml version=1.0-->`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("pre").load("test.xml", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
            alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
});
```

Like that u can get your xml file using jquery. Here you can get the entire xml in the format of string. Then you can play with your own style

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, the problem comes from the final phase, so from a jQuery object to a string, the file is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use dataType: 'xml' within your ajax.
```

Comment: There's nothing about ajax in my script, but maybe if you've an idea how to turn the problem into sonething similar, I could solve the situation...

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've manage to find something little by little...

So at the beginning I had a *jQuery object* namely `xmlComputed`.

I have converted in *Javascript node* using `.get()` function, without any parameter, which returns an *array of nodes*.

The first entry of the array was xml initial tag `<!--xml version=1.0-->`, then the second was a text content, and my main node was the third (index 2) (which solves actually the `Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` problem).

Using the XMLSerializer, as mentionned on many posts, I get a *string* in `xmlString`

```
var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
var xmlString = oSerializer.serializeToString(gpxContent.get()[2]);
```

Then for *escaping*, just following another answer [how to escape xml entities in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918868/how-to-escape-xml-entities-in-javascript) namely

```
if (!String.prototype.encodeHTML) {
  String.prototype.encodeHTML = function () {
    return this.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
               .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
               .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
               .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
               .replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
  };
}
```

And by doing `xmlString.encodeHTML()`, I obtain a quasi prettified text.

Hope it could be useful for someone !